# не получается спарсить страницу на nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

var driver = chrome.setDefaultService(new 
chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());


driver.get('http://css.manual.ru').then(function(elem){
console.log(elem.getText());
});
```

что не так делаю? selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver установил, ругается на get() в этом коде

Comment: Как ругается? Есть ошибка?

Comment: /usr/local/www/mcas-node/test.js:8driver.get('http://css.manual.ru').then(function(elem){
       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/www/mcas-node/test.js:8:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3

Comment: попробуйте заменить `var driver = chrome.setDefaultService(new 
chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());` на `var driver = new webdriver.Builder().            withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();`

Comment: не работает....

Comment: Ошибка такая же самая?

Comment: TypeError: Target browser must be a string, but is <undefined>; did you forget to call forBrowser()?

Comment: `var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).forBrowser('chrome').build();`

Comment: (node:5485) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Server terminated early with status 2

Comment: может такой конструкции не хватает? usingServer(‘http://localhost:4444/wd/hub’).  тогда как развернуть сервер селениума?